# PHP MYSQL Show tracker, how to mark episodes as watched

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP the fun way, by making something useful. I'm making a personal PHP/MYSQL website for tracking watched episodes of tv-shows, and it's going quite good so far, albeit messy.

I have a user table, a episode table and an series table. Each of these are self explanatory I guess. What I want to do is make each user in the user table able to track what episodes have been watched. (Each single episode is in the episode table with a field that joins it with the Series table to keep track)

What I cannot get my head around is this:
How can I track if said user has watched said episode?

The only solutions I've come up with is

1. Add a field in the episodes database with the userID and mark them as 0 or 1, which isn't a very nice solution.
2. Even worse; each user has a "watched_id" field with several values for each watched episodes.

I know enough to know that this is **not** a good approach, 
how can I approach this more effectively?

Comment: Your title is fine IMO, but I cleaned up your Q a bit as it tends to too much non-essential chit-chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a many-to-many relationship using a mapping table ie. named "watched" with the following fields

```
id
user_id
episode_id
watched_at
...
```

Hope that helps. There is a lot of documenteation on the net if your searching for "many-to-many relationship", here is just an example:

http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know of many-to-many relationships, but it really makes sense as I already have relations on my Series and Episodes table, it's like a middle link and makes perfect sense. Now for some reading.